# file.write() not writing in the file

Tags: python, file

I don't why my program doesn't write on the file

It's supposed to write the input on **produtos.txt**

On **novo_supermercado()** is working but I don't why it doesn't on **novo_produto()**. The text documents are on the same folder as the program so i don't think is a problem with path.

I already checked that the code doesn't raise errors, can reach file.write and printed the input to see if it is right.

```
def novo_supermercado():
    with open('supermercados.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(input('\nComo se chama o supermercado que deseja introduzir?\nNome: ')+'\n')

def novo_produto():
    with open('produtos.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(input('\nQue produto deseja introduzir?\nProduto: ')+'\n')
```

[Photo showing Working Space Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjm5Q.png)

[Photo from vscode of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbdDy.png)

[Code that call the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijcyj.png)

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you call `novo_produto`?

Comment: @Guy Yeah I called it

Comment: Where is the code that calls these functions?

Comment: Make sure you have right working directory. The files might be created elsewhere. Try to use an absolute path.

Comment: @user2390182 I put an image of the code that call the function

Comment: So if you run `programa` and enter `"2"`, it works, but it does not work when you enter `"1"`?

Comment: @user2390182 `"1"` is running for me

Comment: Please put a [mcve] extracted from your code into the question. Use text, not images for textual information. You can't copy'n'paste code from images, you can't search them (easily).

Answer (score 0):

Using an absolute path solved the problem!

I messed the files. I had opened **supermecados.txt** on my Working Space Folder and **produtos.txt** opened in a folder in my Working Space Folder

Updated code:

```
def novo_supermercado():
    with open('Ouro7\supermercados.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(input('\nComo se chama o supermercado que deseja introduzir?\nNome: ')+'\n')

def novo_produto():
    with open('Ouro7\produtos.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(input('\nQue produto deseja introduzir?\nProduto: ')+'\n')
```

[Files that were open before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae5aY.png)